# Ionic in app browser opening url in other browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to open website in app not in other browser but its always opening in google chrome app.

```
  constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) {

    const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
      zoom: 'no',
      fullscreen: "yes",
      hidenavigationbuttons: "no",
      toolbar:'no',
      hideurlbar: 'yes',
    }


  const browser = this.iab.create('https://surveyor.igiinsurance.com.pk/', '_blank',{ toolbar: 'no',  hideurlbar: 'yes',
    fullscreen: "yes",location:"no", options});
    browser.show(); 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use it after platform is ready.

```
  constructor(public platform: Platform, private iab: InAppBrowser) {

    const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
      zoom: 'no',
      fullscreen: "yes",
      hidenavigationbuttons: "no",
      toolbar:'no',
      hideurlbar: 'yes',
    }

     this.platform.ready().then( () => {
        const browser = this.iab.create("https://surveyor.igiinsurance.com.pk", '_self',{ toolbar: 'no',  hideurlbar: 'yes',
       fullscreen: "yes",location:"no", options});
     })

  }
```

Code is already tested :)